# Cakephp 3 crop files

Tags: cakephp-3.0, crop

I have a method. It checks which type of files I get. Then I have to convert it. If I have video I convert it to .mp4, if image to png. I put this code in  controller.

**Controller**

```
public function add()
{
    $data = $this->request->data();
    $this->Posts->create($data);
    $this->_checkMultimedia($data);
}

/**
 * @param $data
 * check file
 */
private function _checkMultimedia($data)
{
    if (!empty($data['file-img']['name'])) {
        $this->_cropImage($data['file-img']['name']);
    }
    if (!empty($data['file-video']['name'])) {
        $this->_cropVideo($data['file-video']['name']);
    }
}

/**
 * @param $file
 * crop video
 */
private function _cropVideo($file)
{
    ///
}

/**
 * @param $file
 * crop image
 */
private function _cropImage($file)
{
    ////
}`
```

How can I convert this files. Maybe you cap give me some link or simple examples, becouse I can't search some information

Answer (score 0):

The most widly used tool is

http://www.ffmpeg.org/

You have to download and install it on your server. And instead of writing all this code in controller, write one Compoenent for each of your tasks mentioned above.